# Mutt not sending email when specifying smtp server

Tags: mutt, smtp

I am trying to use `mutt` as my email client, and it works fine for my gmail account. But when I use my work email, it does not send the emails. It doesn't give any error, it just doesn't send them. The line in my `.muttrc` file that causes this problem is:

> set smtp_url = "smtp://mail.my_work_email_server.com:587"

The behaviour does not change when adding the `smtp_pass`, nor does it by altering the name of the email server (i.e. using a 'fictional' server address).

Comment: What about smtp login?

Comment: That's really weird it doesn't give any error message. Are you sure `smtp_url` is set? Is it possible to confirm with `mutt -D | grep smtp_url` ?

Comment: yes, it's definitely set....

Comment: Any messages in syslog? I suppose its possible it decided to write logs there...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same thing and this is what worked for me.

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes

set imap_user = "user@example.com"
set imap_pass = "!HASHEDPASSWORD!"
set folder = imap://mail.example.com/
set spoolfile = imap://mail.example.com/INBOX

# SMTP user auth
# # fill in the right user and pass based on your setup
# # protocols: smtp for TLS (25/587), smtps for SSL (465)
set smtp_url = "smtp://$imap_user@mail.example.com:587"
set smtp_pass = "$imap_pass"

# Where to save copies of outgoing mail
set record = '+Sent'
```

What made it NOT work for me was the order in which things were in the config file and a definition for 'set record' to a folder which was a link to a non existing folder.

When answering 'no' to the question of creating the Folder it was hanging and no traffic was seen towards the SMTP server.

PS: check sourced config files, they might specify conflicting settings and/or in the wrong order.

HTH

Comment: How do you get a hashed password?

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to successfully send mail via SMTP with another mail client on that machine?  Are you able to telnet to your SMTP server and establish a connection?  Are you using STARTTLS?

In mutt, you use the protocol `smtps` to denote a connection that is secured from the beginning with TLS/SSL.  If your mail server is expecting that (and many do these days), that could be your problem.

However, if your mail server expects to use `STARTTLS`, then you use the regular `smtp://` protocol in `smtp_url` and make sure to `set ssl_starttls=yes`.

Here's an example `telnet` session which shows a mailserver that uses STARTTLS:

```
$ telnet smtp.example.com 587
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to smtp.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
EHLO test
250-
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Ok,I'm not an expert in this, so I'll try to give you as much information as possible: 1) I normally use Thunderbird for emailing, and my work account works fine (both receiving and sending). 2) I copied all the info (server name etc) from the Thunderbird account settings to my `.muttrc` file. 3) On the other hand, `mutt` works fine using my gmail account.
4) I could establish a telnet connection to my work email server. 5) I don't know how to use STARTTLS in `mutt`, although I do use it in Thunderbird.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I should write something like 

`set smtp_url = "smtps://mail.my_work_email_server.com:587"`

in my `.muttrc` file (same as with the gmail account). When I do so, I get the following error:

`gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.`

Comment: @user2426172: what happens if you run `telnet mail.my_work_email_server.com 587` and then after the `220` welcome message type `EHLO test`?  Do you get a `250-STARTTLS`?

Comment: yes, I do get a `250-STARTTLS`. I tried adding `set ssl_starttls=yes` to my `.muttrc` file, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a whole day figuring this out and tweaking MANY combinations between different SSL/TLS and ports configurations with no success, until today I finally tried this specifically:

`set ssl_starttls = no`

It seems mutt's default behavior is to try STARTTLS, so you have to specifically tell it **DON'T**

No other configuration was needed besides the obvious `smtp_url` and `smtp_pass`.
I can now perfectly send mail with this `.muttrc`

```
set ssl_starttls = no
set smtp_url = "smtp://user@example.com@mail.example.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "password"
```

That worked with the **Not recommended** configurations of SSL from my email provider. I'm still not able to use the recommended config using 465 port.

This are all the configurations I have tweaked that affects sending mail, if any one else want to try:

```
set ssl_starttls = no    # apparently yes is default.
set ssl_force_tls = yes
set smtp_authenticators = "login"

set smtp_url = "smtp[s]://..."
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"    # some recommend creating the file first: mkdir ~/.mutt && touch ~/.mutt/certificates

set ssl_verify_host = no
set ssl_verify_dates = no
```

Answer (score 0):

Below config in `~/.muttrc` works for me, for sending mail to gmail:

```
set from = "user@gmail.com"
set realname = "user"
set imap_user = "user@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "pwd"
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
set postponed ="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set header_cache =~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates
set smtp_url = "smtps://user@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
set smtp_pass = "pwd"
set move = no 
set imap_keepalive = 900
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but yesterday I spent two hours tracking down why the above-mentioned configurations didn't work for me, and I want to share the solution to save other people time.

The problem was that I needed to accept the certificate from Google's SMTP server at least once, and this requires running mutt without its input redirected, otherwise mutt cannot prompt you to accept the certificate.

By the way, you should select (a) for always, in order for the certificate to be stored in `.mutt/certificates`.  If you select (o) for once, it will use the supplied certificate, but not store it in `.mutt/certificates`.

So run mutt without redirecting the input (this includes piping to standard input), then accept the offered certificate **a**lways.  After that, the next time you run mutt, it should just work because it is using the stored certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a re-occurring bug with the way the SASL libraries communicate with the Google SMTP server.

Try adding this line to your Muttrc file:

```
set smtp_authenticators="plain"
```

This worked for me (recently, when mutt starting doing the same thing on openSUSE 15.3 after and update).

Note: You might also want to add:

```
set ssl_force_tls=yes
```