# Syntax of smtp_url in muttrc

Tags: mutt, smtp

I'm trying to configure `mutt` just for the purpose of sending short report e-mails from a command-line at the end of a `cron` job, on a headless server.

Most advice on mutt is how to set it up fully as your e-mail client on your local machine so forgive the (hopefully) rather obvious question.

The e-mail address is (say) `me@mycompany.com` which is also the smtp  user name. The smtp server as I have it (working perfectly) on thunderbird is let's say, `smtpout.server.net`.

If I'm to set the `smtp_url` in `.muttrc` do I have to say

```
set smtp_url='smtp://me@mycompany.com@smtpout.server.net:465/'
```

It looks unlikely to me with two @ signs in it? And it can't be just `me@smtpout.server.net` because that is not specify to my company.

Finally, I would add that my cron job was using mutt for years with no problem when the username was `me` and the smtp was `smtp.mycompany.com`.

Answer (score 5):

In an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252288/119298) to another question on mutt, the answerer says they have no problems sending to gmail with an entry like

```
set smtp_url = "smtps://user@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
```

So it seems mutt knows about this situation. Other people suggest url-encoding the `@` as `%40` but perhaps it depends on the mutt version.